# Serving gzip assets over HTTPS/SSL with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, gzip

I have a Rails app so when I precompile, gzip assets are also compiled for me. I used the following Apache config to serve up gzip assets:

```
<Location /assets/>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Make sure the browser supports gzip encoding before we send it
    # without it, Content-Type will be "application/x-gzip"

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} \b(x-)?gzip\b
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz [L]
</Location>

# Also add a content-encoding header to tell the browser to decompress

<FilesMatch \.css\.gz$>
    ForceType text/css
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch \.js\.gz$>
    ForceType text/javascript
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
</FilesMatch>
```

However, I noticed this doesn't work on the `https` SSL site. It does work on the `http` site. How do I get Apache to serve up gzip assets on `https`? I don't need to use `mod_deflate` since my gzipped assets are already compiled when I compile my Rails assets.

Comment: Where is this config sitting? I would suspect you have 2 different vhosts SSL and non-SSL and this is only applied to the non-SSL one.

Comment: Oh, this might be only applying to the non-SSL one. This config is sitting in `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Should I also copy it to `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`?

Comment: Ah, that was the issue. I've copied the config to the 443 virtual host and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Capsule mentioned in the comments, I needed to the chunk of gzip config into `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` in addition to `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

Comment: I would just put it in a `.htaccess` file so you don't duplicate the rules, if you can.

Comment: Or just redirect non SSL to SSL and only have one config in the SSL vhost